# any differences contains both 0 and 1.

Tags: coding-theory

**we can always assume, if we wish, any differences contains both 0 and 1.**  $$ $$ A subset $ A=\{a_{1},a_{2},.....,a_{k} \}$ of  group $ G$ is  called a $ (k,\lambda)$ difference set if for each $ a \neq 0$ the equation $ a_{i}-a_{j}=a $ have exactly  $ \lambda $ soltion $ (a_{i},a_{j})$ in A.  Further if $ A$ is a difference set , so is the set $ A+i$ for $ i \in G$.  But i can't apply  it into  work. please help me

Comment: I don't see a question. What are you asking?

Comment: Also, by a group G, do you mean a group as in Group Theory?